# Ruby test about classes, and changing a variable, has me stuck. (I assume VERY simple)

Tags: ruby, variables, testing, instances

I don't understand what to do, or how to solve this.

```
#This is the test
require 'book'

   describe Book do

   before do
   @book = Book.new
   end

   describe 'title' do
   it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
   @book.title = "inferno"
   expect(@book.title).to eq("Inferno")
   end

end
```

I've tried things like this:

```
class Book
   def title string
        @title = string.to_s.capitalize
   end
end

@book = Book.new
puts @book.title("inferno")
```

This works, but fails the test since the test wants:

```
@book.title = "inferno"
```

But everything I've tried with the above line of code fails and I get an error message stating in some way:

```
"undefined method 'title=' for #<Book" etc
```

I don't understand how I can just try to change the value of a variable within a class with an "=" in the open like that. I really don't understand what's going on. I think I'm simply too uneducated at the moment to solve this.

I've seen someone do this online

```
class Book
   def title
      @title
   end

   def title=(title)
      @title = titlieze(title)
   end
end
```

But I have no idea what's going on. Why is there an argument following an "="?

Why is there a 'title' method, then a 'title='?

What is @title = titlieze(title) doing?

Looking at this code, I can't even reverse engineer it and understand what's happening.

If anyone can give me some insights into any of this, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple. `title=` looks like an assignment overloading but it's just a method. A "setter method" if you want. It's what happen when you use `attr_writer`.

```
attr_writer :title
```

is a method that define a `title=` method like this

```
def title=(value)
  @title = value
end
```

Comment: Also known as `virtual attributes`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I still don't entirely understand, but I think you've given me enough to start understanding. Thanks you.

Comment: Serously, it's just a method that ends with = :D

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about TDD and BDD is that – at least assuming you are using a decent testing framework and your tests are well-written – your tests will *tell* you what to do next. You just need to listen to your tests.

At every step, just do the **simplest thing possible to change the message**.

So, let's do that. Let's simply run the test, and listen to what it tells us:

> ```
> lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- book (LoadError)
> ```

Okay, it tells us that it can't find a file named `book`. What's the simplest thing possible to change the message? Well, just create a file named `book.rb`:

```sh
touch book.rb
```

Now run the test again:

> ```
> book_spec.rb:5:in `': uninitialized constant Book (NameError)
> ```

Now, what is the simplest possible thing we can do to change the message? We initialize a constant named `Book`:

```
Book = Object.new
```

Here's the new error we get now:

> ```
> undefined method `new' for #<Object:0x007fbe9c8e4a60>
> ```

Okay, so there is no method `new`? Then we create one. The simplest possible thing is to create a method that does nothing.

```
Book = Object.new
def Book.new; end
```

> ```
> undefined method `title=' for nil:NilClass
> ```

Hmm … it tries to call a method that doesn't exist on the thing that we returned from `new`. Calling `new` and then calling methods on the thing that is returned from `new`, that sounds like the test wants us to create class, right? I mean, that's what you do with a class: you call `new` and then you continue working with the thing that you got back from `new`.

Okay, so let's try what happens when we change the whole thing to a class:

```
class Book; end
```

> ```
> undefined method `title=' for #<Book:0x007f9aa99cd010>
> ```

That wasn't too surprising, we didn't actually fix the error. However! We didn't introduce any new errors either, but we simplified our code. That's still some kind of progress. Now, let's *actually* create our method:

```
class Book
  def title=; end
end
```

> ```
> wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
> ```

That's much better. We managed to change the message. It attempts to pass an argument, but the method doesn't take a parameter. Let's change that:

```
class Book
  def title=(_) end
end
```

> ```
> undefined method `title' for #<Book:0x007fd10102be60>
> ```

We have seen that before, haven't we? And we know how to fix it:

```
class Book
  def title=(_) end
  def title; end
end
```

> ```
> expected: "Inferno"
>      got: nil
> ```

Alright, so the test expected our `title` method to return `"Inferno"`, but it returned `nil` instead. Let's fix that:

```
class Book
  def title=(_) end
  def title; 'Inferno' end
end
```

Hooray! The test passes! Our `Book` class works perfectly! It passes the test, the code is short and easy to read, and it does only the absolute minimal thing it needs to, there is no extraneous fluff.

Okay, well, no, obviously, it doesn't. In a "real" project, the test wouldn't pass yet, there would be another test that tries the same thing but with a different book title. Imagine, the test looked more like this:

```
require 'book'

describe Book do
  before do
    @book = Book.new
  end

  describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @book.title = 'inferno'
      expect(@book.title).to eq('Inferno')
    end

    it 'should leave the first letter capitalized if it is already' do
      @book.title = 'Hannibal'
      expect(@book.title).to eq('Hannibal')
    end
  end
end
```

> ```
> expected: "Hannibal"
>      got: "Inferno"
> ```

This is more helpful: the test tells us that it expected the second test to return `'Hannibal'` instead of the same thing we returned for the first test.

Now, the simplest thing we can do would be to change the code to return `'Hannibal'` instead, but that would be stupid, since it would break the test we have already gotten to pass. Instead, we need to think about what the test is telling us "between the lines". It doesn't want us to *literally* return `'Hannibal'`, it wants us to return back what it gave us in the `title=` method. So, we need to store that somehow.

```
class Book
  def title=(title)
    @title = title
  end

  def title
    @title
  end
end
```

> ```
> expected: "Inferno"
>      got: "inferno"
> ```

Well, we managed to break our first test anyway … but I expected that! After all, I didn't actually do anything to make sure that the name is capitalized. But it is a "useful" breakage, because it actually tells us what we need to do: we need to capitalize the name somehow.

Now we need to make a choice: we can either *store* the name capitalized, then we can simply just return it later, *or* we can store it as it is and *return* it capitalized later. Both of these approaches have their advantages and disadvantages. The first approach has the advantage that the data is *normalized*, i.e. that it is stored in a standardized format. There is no way that we can accidentally return the wrong format since we didn't store it in the first place. But, we lose the *exact* format that the user entered, which means that we can never "go back". For example, if we later want to change the rules about capitalization, we can't do that easily, because we don't know what the original input was.

In a real system, there would probably be other tests or other concerns that would tell us which of the two is the right choice. Right now, I will simply demonstrate both.

```
class Book
  def title=(title)
    @title = title.capitalize
  end

  def title
    @title
  end
end
```

Hooray! The test passes! Now comes the next step when doing BDD: with the confidence that we have a passing testsuite that will catch any mistakes we make, we will *refactor* our code. In this particular case, there is really only one thing we can do: we can replace the trivial `title` method with an attribute reader method by using the [`Module#attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) method, which will generate a method for us that does pretty much the same thing as we did manually:

```
class Book
  attr_reader :title

  def title=(title)
    @title = title.capitalize
  end
end
```

The test still passes, our program is complete.

Here's the other alternative:

```
class Book
  def title=(title)
    @title = title
  end

  def title
    @title.capitalize
  end
end
```

Again, the test passes, and again, the last remaining step is to refactor. This time, it's the `title=` method that is so trivial that we can let [`Module#attr_writer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer) generate it for us:

```
class Book
  attr_writer :title

  def title
    @title.capitalize
  end
end
```

If we *really* want to, we can factor out *how* we want our titles to be transformed into a separate helper method. This has two advantages: if we need to perform this transformation in different places in the code, the knowledge about how to do so is not duplicated in multiple places, it is instead centralized in one place. Note, however, that at the moment, this violates the *YAGNI (You Ain't Gonna Need It)* principle of not trying to predict the future. However, there is a second benefit, and that is that it allows us to attach a name to this transformation. So, we could do something like this:

```
class Book
  attr_reader :title

  def title=(title)
    @title = titleize(title)
  end

  private def titleize(title)
    title.capitalize
  end
end
```

or

```
class Book
  attr_writer :title

  def title
    titleize(@title)
  end

  private def titleize(title)
    title.capitalize
  end
end
```